# I'm unable to get result using this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table Item
(
    Itemid int primary key ,
    ItemName varchar(100),
    CalorificValue int,
    price int 
)
```

[image]

Task: what item has the highest price followed by the highest calorific value?

My query solution:

```
Select Itemname 
from Item 
where price = (Select max(price) from Item)
  and CalorificValue = (Select max(CalorificValue) from Item)
```

But I'm not getting the answer. Can anyone solve this issue?

Comment: please tag which flavor of SQL are you using, SQL server, mySQL etc?

Comment: do you wan the price where there is maximum CalorificValue?

Comment: I think max(Price) is 56000 and max(CalorificValue) is 65, so the query is SELECT ItemName FROM Item WHERE price = 56000 and CalorificValue = 65;  Which is no items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following with `limit`

```
select
    TOP 1 ItemName
from yourTable
order by
    price desc,
    CalorificValue desc
```

Comment: ```Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.```

Comment: @ALI which SQL engine are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL SERVER 2018